# Correct way to dispose a batch of Memory streams in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code but am worried about the creation of a `List<MemoryStream>` just so I can dispose them in the try..finally block

```
/// <summary>
/// Emit a batch of log events, running to completion asynchronously.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="events">The events to emit.</param>
/// <remarks>Override either <see cref="PeriodicBatchingSink.EmitBatch"/> or <see cref="PeriodicBatchingSink.EmitBatchAsync"/>,
/// not both.</remarks>
protected override async Task EmitBatchAsync(IEnumerable<LogEvent> events)
{
    var streams = new List<MemoryStream>();
    try
    {
        var req = new PutRecordsRequest { StreamName = streamName };

        foreach (var logEvent in events)
        {
            var json = await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(logEvent);
            var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            var data = new MemoryStream(payload);

            var entry = new PutRecordsRequestEntry
            {
                PartitionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Data = data
            };

            req.Records.Add(entry);
            streams.Add(data);
        }

        await client.PutRecordsAsync(req);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SelfLog.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        streams.ForEach(x => x.Close());
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks good, but disposing `MemoryStream` isn't actually needed.  The `Close` and `Dispose` members are inherited from `Stream` because file and network streams need them, but do nothing on `MemoryStream` instances.

Comment: Your code is fine, but this is more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com, as you don't appear to have a real question.

Answer (score 1):

When that `streams` is only used in the finally then you're better off without it.

A MemoryStream does not actually need to be Disposed (Closed) and when it's in some async pipeline, leave it be. The Garbage collector will reclaim it.

Comment: Even though the (current) implementation of `MemoryStream` does not strictly require explicit disposal, it is good practice to still wrap it in a `using` statement or calling `Dispose` on it manually. It's marked disposable for a reason, and if the implementation changes later down the line you could end up with flawed code.

Comment: I agree. We should still encourage good practice regardless of whether or not it'll ever happen though.

Comment: It's also defensive to call dispose because the memory streams could be replaced by different streams later.

Comment: And it also tells the GC not to run the finalizer, which saves some time.

Comment: @IllidanS4 - I don't think the MemStream has a Finalizer. It shouldn't.

Comment: In this case, you can't use a using block otherwise it would try to dispose the memory stream before the call to `await client.PutRecordsAsync(req);` right?

Comment: @Henk You are right, neither `MemoryStream` nor `Stream` has a finalizer, which surprises me. Doesn't it actually violate the correct implementation of `IDisposable`?

Comment: It doesn't hinder the correct implementation, but it deviates from the canonical one. Unfortunately Microsoft only published a reference for the full implementation, the one you almost never need.